# Express Router with nested params doesn't work

Tags: regex, express, regex-group

I have a working example that matches the desired route path, but I have to recreate the full file name in the controller from the param 'cameraname' and the knowing the rest of the filename.  Here's the code that works like that:

```
 this.router.get(
      `${this.path}/watch/:cameraname([a-zA-Z\_]+).m3u8`,
      [authMiddleware()],
      this.camerasController.getHLSPlaylist,
    )
```

I wish to modify this with the addition of a parameter that includes the filename extension like this:

```
 this.router.get(
      `${this.path}/watch/:filename(:cameraname([a-zA-Z\_]+).m3u8)`,
      [authMiddleware()],
      this.camerasController.getHLSPlaylist,
    )
```

But that doesn't work (no matches).  Here's an example of the request path:

```
/cameras/watch/Garage_Door.m3u8
```

This first code works, but not the second.  There are more routes similar to this that are more complex with more parameters.  This case is the simplest.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) does not mention the possiblity of nested parameters.

But

```js
this.router.get(
  `${this.path}/watch/:cameraname([a-zA-Z\_]+).:suffix`,
  ...)
```

works and gives you the suffix (that is, the rest of the filename) as `req.params.suffix`.

Does that cover your requirement?

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Yes, that satisfies the case that I presented here.  However, there are others in the router that are more complex and are probably best left as they are.  Thanks again.